# XamlParseException with LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap

Trying to query LDAP

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
de.Path = @"dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=edu";
de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous;

foreach (DirectoryEntry user in de.Children)
{
```

I get the exception.

I have also tried with adding `"LDAP://"` to path and `"cn=users,"` to path

Same happens with

```
DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(de);
srch.FindOne();
```

Exception is

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'LDAPTest2.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

We use Open Directory and I use same settings with other programs to list users.

**EDIT:**
As per `marc_s` suggestion I have tried the same with `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` but I get the same exception on `Bind()`

```
LdapConnection ldapCon;
ldapCon = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("xxx.xxx.xxx.edu", 389));
ldapCon.AuthType = AuthType.Anonymous;                
ldapCon.Bind();
```

Comment: `System.DirectoryServices` is for **Active Directory** only - if you need generic LDAP connectivity, have a look at the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` namespace and its classes